# append for arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, append

I am trying to make a function that will graph ellipses. There are two parameters (a and b) that determine the semi major and major axes of the ellipse. There is another parameter that determines the angle of the ellipse. a, b, and the rotation angle are arrays with three values in each, so they should make three ellipses. There is a third factor, which is the scale factor alpha that each ellipse is multiplied by. I have two values of alpha, and thus six total ellipses.

I am trying to make a for loop that would calculate the parameter of each list and store it in an array. Then I could make plots of various combinations of ellipses from that array.

I keep throwing the error that 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code. a, b and the rotation angle were previously determined with a different function called uncertainty_parameters

```
    import numpy as np
    from math import pi

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.patches as patches
    from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse


    def ellipse_graph(v,A,v0,sigma,sigma_noise,alpha):
    a,b,rotation_angle = uncertainty_parameters(v,A,v0,sigma,sigma_noise,alpha)
    ellipses = []
    alpha = [1.52,2.48]
    for i in range(3):
            el = patches.Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=alpha[j]*2*a[i], height=alpha[j]*2*b[i], angle = rotation_angle[i])
            #####width and height are total (so 2a and 2b), angle in degrees
            ellipses.append(el)
    ellipses = np.array(ellipses) #an array of all 3 ellipses' data
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use different names for lists and arrays.  Lists have an `append` method, arrays do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a Numpy Array, it doesn't have an append method.  It looks like your spacing is a little off in the problem and it's hard to tell whether or not you are converting ellipses into an array in the loop.  If you do want to use append, you may want to wrap `ellipses` in `list` by adding a line like the following in your `for` loop:

```
el = patches.Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=alpha[j]*2*a[i], height=alpha[j]*2*b[i], angle = rotation_angle[i])
        #####width and height are total (so 2a and 2b), angle in degrees
ellipses = ellipses.tolist()
ellipses.append(el)
```

And then at the end, outside the loop:

```
ellipses = np.asarray(ellipses)
```

That will convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

your code as posted should work.
when you get the error, is it a different version of the code in which that final 

    `ellipses = np.array(ellipses) #an array of all 3 ellipses' data`

has been included inside the loop, such that ellipses becomes an ndarray during the loop (and has no append method)?

Regardless, iterating and appending isn't the most pythonic way to do this. 
If you were working purely with ndarrays, you would preallocate at the size you need and assign to ellipses[i] in the loop.

Even more pythonic is to use a *list comprehension*. You can the entire for loop with a single list builder:

    `ups = uncertainty_parameters(v,A,v0,sigma,sigma_noise,alpha)
    ellipses = [patches.Ellipse(
                    xy=(0, 0), width=alpha[j] * 2 * a,
                    height=alpha[j] * 2 * b, angle = rotation_angle)
                for a, b, rotation_angle in zip(ups)]
    ellipses = np.array(ellipses)`

(this is makes it easier to see that a, b, and rotation_angle are being stepped together, and that a list is being produced)